# Procedures in Bigquery with default parameters

Tags: google-bigquery

I am creating a procedure in `Bigquery` to which I want to pass a parameter, in this case the name of a table. But if nothing is passed to the procedure, it will assign a value by default.

This is what I currently have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `MY_DATASET.MY_PROCEDURE`(tableName STRING)
BEGIN

  DECLARE tableName STRING DEFAULT "MY_TABLE";
  DECLARE queryString STRING;

  SET queryString = SELECT * FROM MY_DATASET.tableName;

END;
```

This is the error it currently shows me:

`Variable 'tableName' previously declared as an argument`

If I don't pass any parameters to the procedure, the query is as follows:

```
SELECT `MY_DATASET.MY_PROCEDURE`();
```

`queryString = SELECT * FROM MY_DATASET.MY_TABLE;`

But if I pass a table to the procedure, I need it to create the following query:

```
SELECT `MY_DATASET.MY_PROCEDURE`('TABLE_TEST');
```

`queryString = SELECT * FROM MY_DATASET.TABLE_TEST;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try and consider the below possible workaround.

Since passing a `NULL` value on a declared parameter will result to `expects 1 argument(s), 0 provided` error, you may just pass an **empty string** and then use an `IF statement` to handle your desired **default value** if an empty string is passed.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `MY_DATASET.MY_PROCEDURE`(tableName STRING)
BEGIN
DECLARE table_Name STRING;
DECLARE queryString STRING;

SET table_Name = IF (tableName = '', 'MY_TABLE', tableName);

SET queryString = " SELECT * FROM MY_DATASET."||table_Name||"";

SELECT queryString;

END
```

**Output using empty string parameter:**

```sql
CALL SELECT `MY_DATASET.MY_PROCEDURE`('');
```

[image]

**Output using a passed parameter:**

```sql
CALL `MY_DATASET.MY_PROCEDURE`('TABLE_TEST');
```

[image]